# Classic ASP file upload issue

Tags: file-upload, vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to upload a csv file then read it line by line and pass it to my Database. I have a issue on file upload I could see that whenever I upload a file an extra number gets added to a column in my csv and due to this my code fails. I could see that the file gets saved in the expected location and when I opened it I could see an extra number which I never added. What could be the reason for this?

[image: this is my csv file that got uploaded in server having that extra value]

Here is my code for uploading the CSV file and reading it and using a loop I'm iterating the values in the csv file and storing the values in my variables which is then passed to a method to store in DB.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<!--#include file="clsUpload.asp"-->
<!-- #include file = "Bin/includes/GenFunctions.asp" -->
<!-- #include file = "Bin/includes/HeaderFooter.asp" -->
</HEAD>
<title>CMTL Entry File Upload</title>
<%showHeader%>
<BODY text="#000000" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<FORM ACTION = "clsUploadtest.asp" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" METHOD="POST">
File Name: <INPUT TYPE=FILE NAME="txtFile"><P>
<INPUT TYPE = "SUBMIT" NAME="cmdSubmit" VALUE="SUBMIT">
</FORM><P>
<%

'Declare the form variables
Dim intRecordId
Dim strRecordId
Dim strAction
Dim strInputDate
Dim strPayer
Dim strAmount
Dim strTransType
Dim strPayee
Dim strAddRemarks
Dim strComments
Dim strAccNo
Dim strPolicyNo
Dim strBranchConfDate
Dim strConfBy
Dim strSheetUpdDate
Dim strMailUpdDate
Dim strUploadTime
Dim strUploadId
Dim strStatus
Dim strLastMdfdDate
Dim strLastMdfdId
Dim lineData
Dim  code
Dim name
Dim mail
Dim id
Dim price
Dim amount
Dim MyArray
Dim i 
i = 0

set obj = Server.CreateObject("AC_FI.mMTL")
If err.number <> 0 Then
    RaiseGenError objCMTL,"Error while creating the object "
    Response.End
end if

set o = new clsUpload
if o.Exists("cmdSubmit") then
'get client file name without path

sFileSplit = split(o.FileNameOf("txtFile"), "\")
sFile = sFileSplit(Ubound(sFileSplit))

o.FileInputName = "txtFile"
o.FileFullPath = Server.MapPath(".") & "\entry\" & sFile
o.save

 if o.Error = "" then
    response.write "Success. File saved to  " & o.FileFullPath  
 else
    response.write "Failed due to the following error: " & o.Error
end if

set fso = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
set fs = fso.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath("entry/" & sFile), 1, False)

 Do While Not fs.AtEndOfStream 
    lineData = fs.ReadLine
    'lineData = replace(lineData,chr(13),",")
    'lineData = replace(lineData,chr(34),"")
     MyArray = Split(lineData , ",")
     strRecordId=MyArray(0)
     strInputDate=MyArray(1)
     strPayer=MyArray(2)
     strAmount=MyArray(3)
     strTransType=MyArray(4)
     strPayee=MyArray(5) 
     strAddRemarks=MyArray(6)
     strComments=MyArray(7)
     strAccNo=MyArray(8)
     strPolicyNo=MyArray(9)
     strBranchConfDate=MyArray(10)
     strConfBy=MyArray(11)
     strSheetUpdDate=MyArray(12)
     strMailUpdDate=MyArray(13)
     strUploadTime=MyArray(14)
     strUploadId=MyArray(15)
     strStatus=MyArray(16)
      strRecordId       = convertNullString(strRecordId)
     strAction          = convertNullString(strAction)
     strInputDate       = convertNullDate(strInputDate)
    strPayer            = convertNullString(strPayer)
    strAmount           = convertNullString(strAmount)
    strTransType        = convertNullString(strTransType)
    strPayee            = convertNullString(strPayee)
    strAddRemarks       = convertNullString(strAddRemarks)
    strComments         = convertNullString(strComments)
    strAccNo            = convertNullString(strAccNo)
    strPolicyNo         = convertNullString(strPolicyNo)
    strBranchConfDate   = convertNullDate(strBranchConfDate)
    strConfBy           = convertNullString(strConfBy)
    strSheetUpdDate     = convertNullDate(strSheetUpdDate)
    strMailUpdDate      = convertNullDate(strMailUpdDate)
    strUploadTime       = convertNullDate(strUploadTime)
    strUploadId         = convertNullString(strUploadId)
    strStatus           = convertNullString(strStatus)
        intRecordId = obj.InsertData(strInputDate,strPayer,strAmount,strTransType,strPayee,strAddRemarks,_
                    strComments,strAccNo,strPolicyNo,strBranchConfDate,strConfBy,strSheetUpdDate,_
                    strMailUpdDate,strUploadTime,strUploadId,strStatus, pErrorcode)
    i=i+1
Loop 

fs.close() 
set fs = nothing
set fso = nothing
end if
set o = nothing

%>
<%showFooter%>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

this is the clsupload.asp file that I have used for file upload

```
<%
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Container of Field Properties
Class clsField
    Public FileName
    Public ContentType
    Public Value
    Public FieldName
    Public Length
    Public BinaryData
End Class
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Class clsUpload
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Private nFieldCount
    Private oFields()
    Private psFileFullPath
    Private psError
    Private psFileInputName
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Public Property Get Count()
        Count = nFieldCount
    End Property
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Public Default Property Get Field(ByRef asFieldName)
        Dim lnLength
        Dim lnIndex
        
        lnLength = UBound(oFields)
        
        If IsNumeric(asFieldName) Then
            If lnLength >= asFieldName And asFieldName > -1 Then
                Set Field = oFields(asFieldName)
            Else
                Set Field = New clsField
            End If
        Else
            For lnIndex = 0 To lnLength
                If LCase(oFields(lnIndex).FieldName) = LCase(asFieldName) Then
                    Set Field = oFields(lnIndex)
                    Exit Property
                End If
            Next
            Set Field = New clsField
        End If
    End Property
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Public Function Exists(ByRef avKeyIndex)
        Exists = Not IndexOf(avKeyIndex) = -1
    End Function
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Public Property Get ValueOf(ByRef avKeyIndex)
        Dim lnIndex
        lnIndex = IndexOf(avKeyIndex)
        if lnIndex = -1 Then Exit Property
        ValueOf = oFields(lnIndex).Value
    End Property
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Public Property Get FileNameOf(ByRef avKeyIndex)
        Dim lnIndex
        lnIndex = IndexOf(avKeyIndex)
        if lnIndex = -1 Then Exit Property
        FileNameOf = oFields(lnIndex).FileName
    End Property
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Public Property Get LengthOf(ByRef avKeyIndex)
        Dim lnIndex
        lnIndex = IndexOf(avKeyIndex)
        if lnIndex = -1 Then Exit Property
        LengthOf = oFields(lnIndex).Length
    End Property
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Public Property Get BinaryDataOf(ByRef avKeyIndex)
        Dim lnIndex
        lnIndex = IndexOf(avKeyIndex)
        if lnIndex = -1 Then Exit Property
        BinaryDataOf = oFields(lnIndex).BinaryData
    End Property
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Private Function IndexOf(ByVal avKeyIndex)
        Dim lnIndex
        
        If avKeyIndex = "" Then
            IndexOf = -1
        ElseIf IsNumeric(avKeyIndex) Then
            avKeyIndex = CLng(avKeyIndex)
            If nFieldCount > avKeyIndex And avKeyIndex > -1 Then
                IndexOf = avKeyIndex
            Else
                IndexOf = -1
            End If
        Else
            For lnIndex = 0 To nFieldCount - 1
                If LCase(oFields(lnIndex).FieldName) = LCase(avKeyIndex) Then
                    IndexOf = lnIndex
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Next
            IndexOf = -1
        End If
    End Function
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Property Let FileFullPath(sValue)
    psFileFullPath = sValue
End Property
'___________________________________________________________________________________
Public Property Get FileFullPath()
    FileFullPath = psFileFullPath 
End Property
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Property Let FileInputName(sValue)
    psFileInputName = sValue
End Property
' --------------------  ----------------------------------------------------------
Public Function Save()
    if psFileFullPath <> "" and psFileInputName <> "" then
        'Save to connectionless client side recordset, write to stream,
        'and persist stream.

        'would think you should be able to write directly to
        'stream without recordset, but I could not get that to work

        On error resume next
        binData = o.BinaryDataOf(psFileInputName)
    
        set rs = server.createobject("ADODB.RECORDSET")
        rs.fields.append "FileName", 205, LenB(binData)
        rs.open
        rs.addnew
        rs.fields(0).AppendChunk binData 
        
        if err.number = 0 then
            set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
            objStream.Type  = 1
            objStream.Open
            objStream.Write rs.fields("FileName").value 
            objStream.SaveToFile psFileFullPath, 2
            objStream.close
            set objStream = Nothing

        ENd if
        rs.close
        set rs = nothing
        psError = Err.Description
else
        psError = "One or more required properties (FileFullPath and/or FileInputName) not set"

  End If


End Function

Public Property Get Error()
    Error = psError
End Property


' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Public Property Get ContentTypeOf(ByRef avKeyIndex)
        Dim lnIndex
        lnIndex = IndexOf(avKeyIndex)
        if lnIndex = -1 Then Exit Property
        ContentTypeOf = oFields(lnIndex).ContentType
    End Property

' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Private Sub Class_Terminate()
        Dim lnIndex
        For lnIndex = 0 To nFieldCount - 1
            Set oFields(0) = Nothing
        Next
    End Sub
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        
        Dim lnBytes             ' Bytes received from the client
        Dim lnByteCount         ' Number of bytes received
        Dim lnStartPosition     ' Position at which content begins
        Dim lnEndPosition       ' Position at which content ends
        
        Dim loDic               ' Contains properties of each
                                ' specific field
                                ' Local dictionary object(s) 
                                ' to be appended to class-scope
                                ' dictionary object.
                                
        Dim lnBoundaryBytes     ' Bytes contained within the current boundary
        Dim lnBoundaryStart     ' Position at which the current boundary begins
                                ' within the lnBytes binary data.
        Dim lnBoundaryEnd       ' Position at which the current boundary ends
                                ' within the lnBytes binary data.
        Dim lnDispositionPosition
        
        Dim lsFieldName         ' Name of the current field being parsed from
                                ' Binary Data
        Dim lsFileName          ' Name of the file within the current boundary
        Dim lnFileNamePosition  ' Location of file name within current boundary
        Dim loField             ' clsField Object
        Dim lsValue             ' Value of the current field
        Dim lsContentType       ' ContentType of the binary file (MIME Type)
        
        ' Initialize Fields
        nFieldCount = 0
        ReDim oFields(-1)
        
        ' Read the bytes (binary data) into memory  
        lnByteCount = Request.TotalBytes
        lnBytes = Request.BinaryRead(lnByteCount)
        
        'Get the lnBoundaryBytes
        lnStartPosition = 1
        lnEndPosition = InstrB(lnStartPosition, lnBytes, CStrB(vbCr))
        
        If lnEndPosition >= lnStartPosition Then
            lnBoundaryBytes = MidB(lnBytes, lnStartPosition, lnEndPosition - lnStartPosition)
        End If
        
        lnBoundaryStart = InstrB(1, lnBytes, lnBoundaryBytes)
        
        
        ' Loop until the BoundaryBytes begin with "--"
        Do Until (lnBoundaryStart = InstrB(lnBytes, lnBoundaryBytes & CStrB("--")))
        
            ' All data within this boundary is stored within a local dictionary
            ' to be appended to the class-scope dictionary.
            
            ReDim Preserve oFields(nFieldCount)
            nFieldCount = nFieldCount + 1
            
            Set loField = New clsField

            lnDispositionPosition = InstrB(lnBoundaryStart, lnBytes, CStrB("Content-Disposition"))
            
            ' Get an object name
            lnStartPosition = InstrB(lnDispositionPosition, lnBytes, CStrB("name=")) + 6
            lnEndPosition = InstrB(lnStartPosition, lnBytes, CStrB(""""))
            lsFieldName = CStrU(MidB(lnBytes, lnStartPosition, lnEndPosition - lnStartPosition))
            loField.FieldName = lsFieldName
            
            ' Get the location fo the file name.
            lnFileNamePosition = InstrB(lnBoundaryStart, lnBytes, CStrB("filename="))
            lnBoundaryEnd = InstrB(lnEndPosition, lnBytes, lnBoundaryBytes)
            
            'Test if object is a file
            If Not lnFileNamePosition = 0 And lnFileNamePosition < lnBoundaryEnd Then
            
                ' Parse Filename
                lnStartPosition = lnFileNamePosition + 10
                lnEndPosition =  InstrB(lnStartPosition, lnBytes, CStrB(""""))
                lsFileName = CStrU(MidB(lnBytes,lnStartPosition,lnEndPosition-lnStartPosition))
                loField.FileName = lsFileName               
                
                ' Parse Content-Type
                lnStartPosition = InstrB(lnEndPosition,lnBytes,CStrB("Content-Type:")) + 14
                lnEndPosition = InstrB(lnStartPosition,lnBytes,CStrB(vbCr))
                lsContentType = CStrU(MidB(lnBytes,lnStartPosition,lnEndPosition-lnStartPosition))
                loField.ContentType = lsContentType

                ' Parse Content
                lnStartPosition = lnEndPosition + 4
                lnEndPosition = InstrB(lnStartPosition,lnBytes,lnBoundaryBytes)-2
                lsValue = MidB(lnBytes,lnStartPosition,lnEndPosition-lnStartPosition)
                loField.BinaryData = lsValue & CStrB(vbNull)
                loField.Length = LenB(lsValue)
            Else

                ' Parse Content
                lnStartPosition = InstrB(lnDispositionPosition, lnBytes, CStrB(vbCr)) + 4
                lnEndPosition = InstrB(lnStartPosition, lnBytes, lnBoundaryBytes) - 2
                lsValue = CStrU(MidB(lnBytes,lnStartPosition,lnEndPosition-lnStartPosition))
                loField.Value = lsValue
                loField.Length = Len(lsValue)
            End If

            Set oFields(UBound(oFields)) = loField

            'Loop to next object
            lnBoundaryStart = InstrB(lnBoundaryStart + LenB(lnBoundaryBytes), lnBytes, lnBoundaryBytes)
            
            Set loField = Nothing
            
        Loop

    End Sub
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Private Function CStrU(ByRef psByteString)
        Dim lnLength
        Dim lnPosition
        lnLength = LenB(psByteString)
        For lnPosition = 1 To lnLength
            CStrU = CStrU & Chr(AscB(MidB(psByteString, lnPosition, 1)))
        Next
    End Function
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Private Function CStrB(ByRef psUnicodeString)
        Dim lnLength
        Dim lnPosition
        lnLength = Len(psUnicodeString)
        For lnPosition = 1 To lnLength
            CStrB = CStrB & ChrB(AscB(Mid(psUnicodeString, lnPosition, 1)))
        Next
    End Function
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
End Class
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%>
```

You can see that the file has an extra value added in it and  code fails. I have no idea from where this value comes in each time I upload the file. The file in my local machine doesn't have that value. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you [edit] and add the clsUpload.asp file you are using? There are many versions of this file. Also, as a workaround, you could enclose all the array access code within a  `If UBound(MyArray) > 0 Then`  check to bypass this.

Comment: I have edited and added the clsUpload.asp file . Hope this helps everyone to solve this confusing problem that I am facing

Comment: This line -> `loField.BinaryData = lsValue & CStrB(vbNull)` in the clsUpload.asp file is causing the 1 to be added at the end. Keeping it as `loField.BinaryData = lsValue`  seems to fix the problem, but I am not sure why it is there in the first place.

Comment: Is there a carriage return at the end of your csv file which your script is treating as an extra line?  NB do you know that you can use a csv file as an ODBC data source.  I find it a lot easier to pull data that way than to use FileSystemObject

Comment: @john i was trying to reuse a method that already existed for data entry . Can you show me an example  of the way you are suggesting

Comment: There's a guide to setting it up here.  https://help.interfaceware.com/kb/606/5 You can then connect to it as a named ODBC data source and query it using the csv filename as a table name, eg `SELECT * from yourfile.csv ORDER BY id DESC` .  In Windows 7 and above you need to use the 32 bit ODBC manager